# When i want to see if PostgreSQL is working i recive an error code

Tags: postgresql, psql, sudo

when i try to see if PostgreSQL is working writing **sudo -u postgre psql** it gives me this error
*sudo: unknown user: postgre
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

---

Comment: `postgres`, not `postgre`.

Comment: i know i just wrote it wrong

Comment: Do you have PostgreSQL installed? How did you install it?

Comment: i wrote "sudo apt-get install postrgresql"

Comment: Then install the server package as well.

Comment: You wrote it wrong when reporting it to us (both in the command and in the error message)? Or you wrote it wrong when actually executing it?  When running commands, you need to spell them correctly.

Comment: How is this question connected to [tag:elixir]? I have removed the tag.